# How to give proper file and directory permission for magento localhost

Tags: magento2, file-permissions, ubuntu

[image]

Hi i am using Ubuntu 18 and apache2

when i setup magento 2 on localhost

always have file permission problems and also

whenever i run

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

it will cancel all file permission

**already tried comment**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/www/html/myproject/*
```

My Question:
1)How give proper **file and directory** permission to my magento project

Comment: what did you mean

Comment: on console you  are getting 404 thair is i think no issue of permistion is your admin panel is same as fronend? like css not aplied....

Comment: how to i solve this

Comment: admin panel also prints like this

Answer (score 0):

As per recommendations of Magento, the folder and file permission for Magento 2 installation should be like:

> cd <your Magento install dir>
>
> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644
>   permission for files
>
> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755
>   permission for directory
>
> find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777
>   permission for var folder
>
> find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>
> find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>
> chmod 777 ./app/etc
>
> chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
>
> chown -R : .
>
> chmod u+x bin/magento

Also, add the user to the www-data group with...

```
sudo adduser {username} www-data
```

Comment: You have to be root to change the owner of files/directories.
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/magento/

Comment: can i run using sudo

Comment: Yes run using sudo.

Comment: sudo adduser {username} www-data   -  which user i can add  root or user1

Comment: Your current user.

Comment: how to add current user shows does not exiest

Comment: Open a Terminal and type command whoami you will get the current username. then type sudo adduser USERNAME www-data

Comment: After running comments still not working  what i do (can i deploy the project)

Comment: remove var/ generated/ (pub/static/ except .htaccess) and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy, or if you want for multiple languages:

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US ro_RO

Comment: i'm not having that folder remove var/ generated/ (pub/static

Comment: just flush the cache and content deploy.