# Command line user does not have read and write permissions on generated directory. Please address this issue before using Magento command line

Tags: magento2, cli, file-permissions

My Magento site is down and I see

> main.CRITICAL: Cannot write to the "/var/www/html/var/debug/db.log"
>   file. Unable to write {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot
>   write to the \"/var/www/html/var/debug/db.log\" file. Unable to write
>   at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/File/Write.php:54)"}
>   []

I tried `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` but I get

> Command line user does not have read and write permissions on
>   generated directory. Please address this issue before using Magento
>   command line.

I tried changing the permission of generated directory by  `sudo chmod 0777 -R  generated` but still no success. Any advice would be great help.

**Update :** These are the owners of var/log and generated directory

```
/var/www/html# ls -la var/log generated
generated:
total 16
drwxrwsrwx  3 ubuntu www-data 4096 Apr  6 06:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 ubuntu www-data 4096 Apr  6 08:42 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu www-data  126 Jan 19 20:01 .htaccess
drwxrwsrwx  2 ubuntu www-data 4096 Apr  6 10:43 code

var/log:
total 436820
drwxrwsr-x  3 ubuntu www-data      4096 Mar 17 05:58 .
drwxrwsr-x 12 ubuntu www-data      4096 Apr  6 07:56 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data      7180 Feb  2 13:55 4-1549115600.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data       409 Feb  3 11:27 Amasty-inventory-19-02-03.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data   1352583 Apr  3 14:00 cache-warmer.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data    793265 Apr  3 14:45 connector.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data 405626880 Apr  6 10:51 debug.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data   8498179 Apr  6 06:23 exception.log
drwxrwsr-x  2 ubuntu www-data      4096 Feb 24 13:49 firebear
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data    483328 Apr  6 10:51 magento.cron.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data     36864 Apr  6 10:51 setup.cron.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data         0 Feb 10 13:19 shippingaddress_process.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data  30228480 Apr  6 10:51 system.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data         0 Feb  2 09:39 update.cron.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu www-data       870 Mar 19 10:15 update.log
```

Comment: you need to give file and floder permission to that magento root floders

Comment: Error is about /var/www/html/var/debug/db.log so You can change permission of this file or apply all permissions from prabhakaran7 answer, this should help also.

Comment: @BartZalas I have given 777 permission to db.log file but it did not helped

Comment: What user do you use to login to the console? You should use user ubuntu to  run magento  commands in your case

Comment: From which user are you trying to execute setup:di:compile command. The issue seems to be with ownership.

Comment: @RajMohanR user ubuntu

Comment: Can you please try these steps, log in as the root user and try these commands 1.cd <your Magento install dir>
2.find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
3.find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
4.sudo chown -R :<web server group> .
5.chmod u+x bin/magento   Please follow this and let know what happens then

Comment: Have you found solutions for this issue, i have same issue. Please share your solutions.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to try this answer

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251718/73525

i hope this will helpful.

Comment: no this is not helping

Comment: tried all the commands, still no success

Comment: which  os your using

Comment: using windows and my magento is hosted on linux ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I used the below commands and it solves my issue every time.

```
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -f bin/magento cache:clean
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
cd ..
chmod 777 -R html
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, the following solved:

```
sudo chown <user> -R *
```